# Call JS function in webview from Static fragment

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I am trying to have a tabular activity which is automatically setup for me when I creaked my project by selecting the navigation type of "fixed tabs + swype". In each tab I load up a webview that changes URL based on tab. In one tab though I want to call a JS function that lives on the page the webview is going to. I tried all sorts of things with no luck, the JS function works but for some reason its not being called.

The url in the code below is not the URL I'm actually using, also for reference here is the JS function

```
function callFromActivity(msg){
    document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 5 total pages.
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            case 3:
                return getString(R.string.title_section4).toUpperCase(l);
            case 4:
                return getString(R.string.title_section5).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);
        View htmlView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_wvtc,container,false);
        WebView wc = (WebView) htmlView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        // dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1 )
        {

            wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/index.html");
            wc.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity('some msg')");

            wc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return htmlView;
        }
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 2 )
        {

            wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/request.html");

            wc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null ) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });

            return htmlView;
        }
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 3 )
        {

            wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/recent.html");
            wc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null ) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return htmlView;
        }
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 4 )
        {

            wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/queue.html");
            wc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null ) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return htmlView;
        }
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 5 )
        {

            wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/webcam.html");
            wc.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url != null ) {

                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
            return htmlView;
        }
        else {
            return rootView;
        }
    }

 }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait for the document load complete before execute the java script. You can use a `WebChromeClient` to watch the load progress.

```
private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    private WebView mWebView;
    public MyWebChromeClient(WebView webView)
    {
        mWebView = webView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        if (newProgress == 100) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity('some msg')");
        }
    }
}
```

set the `MyWebChromeClient` to `WebView`

```
wc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wc.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/android/index.html");
wc.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(wc));
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I thought it might have something to do with waiting for the page to be loaded but figured if it was someone would know. Thanks a lot!