# How to call JavaScript from webview in fragment?

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview

Below code, I am using to load webview in fragment and I want to call JavaScript function from webview but below code is not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public void loadUrlInWebView(String url,String positon)
        {
        WebViewFragment fragment =  new WebViewFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("url",url);
        fragment.setArguments(data);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }

        var url ="javascript:mobileApp.openLoginMenu()";
            loadUrlInWebView(url,null);
}

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment{
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        url = getArguments().getString("url");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(getActivity()),"AndroidJSObject");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            }
        });
        return rootView;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please follow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775056/call-js-function-in-webview-from-static-fragment

Comment: thank you for suggestion , but my problem is localhost javascript function is not getting called .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call a javascript into android you can call `addJavascriptInterface()`.

For more explanation please follow this link [Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

And the thing to keep in mind is,

When you want to call an `android` method from `javascript` method, the method name should be called on the string name you have provided while calling `addJavascriptInterface()` precisely in your case something like this in your javascript

```
AndroidJSObject.yourmethod
```

Inside javascript file.

Comment: i have already added addJavascriptInterface() method on webview but it is  not working

Comment: what is not working ?? Where is your `html` file has been kept?

Comment: my html file is on local host server

Comment: Then pass the `url` of local host server. You are not passing the url in the webview.

Comment: in above code, i am passing url like this var url ="javascript:mobileApp.openLoginMenu()";

Comment: loadUrlInWebView(url,null);

Comment: Change  `var url ="javascript:mobileApp.openLoginMenu()";` to this one  `var url ="javascript:alert("My message")";` and see if it shows alert in your app.

Comment: Have you visited the url i have provided to you?  Is any link like google or `var url = "https://www.google.com";` is this working in your app just check

Comment: https://www.google.com link is working in my app but javascript call from fragment is not working

Comment: Okk https://www.google.com/search?q=calling+a+javascript+in+android+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

if `android:targetSdkVersion >=17`

add `@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")` in `onCreated` method

and

```
class InJavaScript {
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void runOnAndroidJavaScript(String status) {
            collectionStatus.setCollectionStatus(status);
        }
    }
```

watch out @JavasscriptInterface.